# Importing project from Eclipse to Android Studio giving error of no resource found

Tags: android, android-studio

When I import the whole project from eclipse to android studio. It imported successfully but while compiling the code it gives me error :

1. Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/home').
2. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\K purohit\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0_rc3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I had tried all the type of available solution on net but it not resolving
Restart not working delete rename also not working

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:src="@drawable/home"/>
```

Comment: You can check is that home image existed in drawables or not?

Comment: It is there. I already checked

Comment: did you try to clean project then run it?

Comment: yes i had already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I had a Answer for my first point

- Delete mipmap folder from project.
- clean the set up.
- restrt the studio.
- rebuild the solution

it works for me...

for second point

update the android studio and sdk wit latest updates. Rebuild the solution it wil work